# Implement a contextual action bar to recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, contextual-action-bar

How can i add a contextual action bar to a recyclerview to handle long press on items to allow an user to delete them? I already have a working recyclerview
Have anybody used this library https://github.com/afollestad/material-cab ?

Comment: "I already have a working recyclerview" -- then add a long-click listener to your item views, and have it open the CAB. There is nothing unique to `RecyclerView` here. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/ActionModeList and https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/ActionModeList2 for sample implementations.

Comment: @CommonsWare What are the key differences between the two github samples you recommended above?

Comment: @AJW: One has a "2" on the end. :-) More seriously, `ActionModeList2` is the more complete sample, actually affecting the model data. `ActionModeList` implements the action mode but then does not really do anything in response to it.

Comment: @CommonsWare 2:nice!  I appreciate the reply.

Comment: @CommonsWare I noticed a getAdapter() method in the RecyclerViewActivity class.  Was that just a generic helper method you set up?  I didn't see getAdapter() used anywhere in any of the code.

Comment: @AJW: Yes, just to show the similarities to `ListActivity`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Very good, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you should refer the following link it will help you
http://www.edumobile.org/android/contextual-action-bar-cab-part2/
it explain the Contextual Action Bar in details

it worked for me

Comment: the link you provide is useful to create contextual-action bar...but how can i combine this with recyclerview item selection?

Comment: The specific problematic is to implement contextual action with recycler view but the article doesn't speak about recycler view.

Comment: am geting remote api data and set to adapter how to implement multiitem selection with contextual action mode for deleta records please help me